# java script validation to force user to enter # as first character in password

Tags: javascript

I have 2 text box(UserName,password),1 Submit Button.I want a java script to force user to start # as 1st character in the password textbox(Alert:"password should start with #").Any Help appreciated very much

Comment: Enforcing `#` as the first character of all passwords arguably *reduces* their strength. Why would you do that?

Comment: Why not just have them enter any password they want and then prepend #? As Frederic says - if everyone has to do it then what's the point?

Comment: client's requirement.It seems they want to group different users to start with different characters as their groups 1st character for the password field.

Answer (score 1):

This code will make sure that the first character in the field with ID `passfield` starts with a sharp. I hope that your "password" field isn't requesting a real password, because forcing a password to start with a certain character makes no sense.

```
function validate(){
    var pass = document.getElementById("passfield");
    if(pass.value.charAt(0) != "#"){
        alert("Password should start with a #.");
        //Optionally: Return
        return;
    }
    //Not returned, the input is valid, continue
    // ...
}
```